# Trying to understand mongodb indexes for finding documents with exact and unique value(s)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am reading through mongo docs fro nodejs driver, particularly this index section https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/indexes/#geospatial-indexes and it looks like all of the indexes that they mention are for sortable / searchable data. So I wanted to ask if I need indexes for following use case:

I have this user document structure

```json
{
  email: string,
  version: number,
  otherData: ...
}
```

As far as I understand I can query each user by `_id` and this already has default unique index applied to it? I alos want to query user by email as well, so I created following unique index

```
collection.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Is my understanding correct here that by creating this index I guarantee thaa:

1. Email is always unique
2. My queries like `collection.findOne({email: 'my@email.com'})` are optimised?

Next, I want to perform update operations on user documents, but only on specific versions, so:

```
collection.updateOne({email: '...', version: 2}, update)
```

What index do I need to create in order to optimise this query? Should I be somehow looking into compound indexes for this as I am now using email and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, the unique constraint happens at the db layer so by definition this will be unique, It is worth mentioning that this can affect insert/update performance as this check has to be executed on each of these instances - from my experience you only start feeling this overhead in larger scale ( hundreds of millions of documents in a single collection + thousands of inserts a minutes ).
2. Yes. there is no other way to optimize this further.

> What index do I need to create in order to optimise this query? Should I be somehow looking into compound indexes for this as I am now using email and version?

You want to create a [compound index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/), the syntax will looks like this:

```
collection.createIndex({ email: 1, version: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

I will just say that by definition the (first) `email` index ensures uniqueness, so any additional filtering you add to the query and index will not really affect anything as there will always be only 1 of those emails in the DB. Basically why bother adding a "version" field to the query? if you need it for filtering that's fine but then you won't be needing to alter the existing index.

Comment: Thank you. Reason for using version in a filter is not for uniqueness, rather to guarantee that document wasn't changed. Use case is to get a document, do some "work" then update the document and while updating, I have to goarantee that it didn't change while "work" was being done.